# Как сделать цветное пятно на background?

Tags: css

Как можно сделать такое пятно на background?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Пятно" можно добавить с помощью написания соответствующего кода, предварительно изучив основы HTML и CSS.

Comment: @UModeL прав - лучше научиться... Если совсем лень, можете воспользоваться любым из онлайн-билдеров. Напр.: https://cssgradient.io/

Comment: @cyadvert не правильно градиентом задавать задний фон, так как от высоты контейнера пятно будет так же вытягиваться по высоте.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи: думаю, что Вы не в полной мере знакомы со свойствами фонов и градиентов.

Comment: @UModeL да не в полной мере знаком, пользуюсь градиентом редко.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи: очень зря, что редко. Это чуть ли не отдельный холст для творений ;-)

Comment: У меня вопрос. В сss  мы же можем применить несколько фонов к элементам.                            .myclass {background: background1, background 2, ..., backgroundN;}                                                                                                                                                                                  1й черный фон и растянуть его через background position и  background size а 2му задать радиальный градиент при этом размещая с помощью этих же свойств по центру? или вот так background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse 180px 90px, #a09af1, #000038);

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку spot в absolute, он никак не будет влиять на внутренние элементы.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  display: block;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.black {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.spot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
}
.spot span {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(48,34,21,1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 50px rgba(48,34,21,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="black">
<div class="spot"><span></span></div>
</div>
```